# Android RelativeLayout make Edit Texts take all space

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/aussie_bg_big" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/titleImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/aussie_title_small" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/clearButtonOutput"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/titleImage"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/aussie_clear" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/OutputText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/clearButtonOutput"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/textbox"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/translateButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/OutputText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/translatebuttonselector" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ClearButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/translateButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/aussie_clear" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/InputText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ClearButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/textbox"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

What I'd like to do is:

-> Keep the **"imageBottom"** imageview on the BOTTOM of the activity at all times, *centered horizontally*.

-> Keep the **"imageCenter"** imageview on the center of the activity at all times, *centered horizontally*.

-> Keep **"imageBelowInputText"** imageview below the **InputText** edittext which is located ABOVE **imageCenter**, *aligned to the right*.

-> Keep **"imageBelowOutputText"** imageview below the **OutputText** edittext which is located BETWEEN **imageCenter** and **imageBottom**, *aligned to the right*.

It works fine so far but I'd also like for the edittext views to occupy ALL of the remaining space EQUALLY. Providing different versions of the layout for small, normal, large, x-large screens worked fine, considering I hardcoded each edittext's size in dpi. However, on some layouts, it still looks a bit wrong and misplaced (misaligned). That's why I'm looking for a solution to place the ImageViews accordingly first, and then let the two EditTexts take all the remaining space EQUALLY (important).

So far, I couldn't think of a 100% correct solution. Can you help me out? Thanks!

Comment: a pictorial representation of what you want will be great...

Comment: Refactor your xml layout. I see ids that appear nowhere in the layout(`clearButtonOutput` ?!?!).

Comment: Sorry about that; re-posted the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the two edittexts have their layout_height set to "0dp" and layout_weight set to "1"
XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Clear" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Bear" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Clear" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Speaking Aussie" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's close to what I'd like to achieve; I could share a picture, but I think it would be even better to further explain on your example: remove the third text box. Center button1 horizontally and vertically. Textbox 1 is above button1, textbox2 is below button1. Button2 is below textbox2. Textbox1 and 2 have equal sizes and take up all remaining space (left by the two buttons which are fixed in size). That's what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: Cool, let me give it a try. The top edit text seems to be a bit larger though.

Comment: It is. Since button1 is at the center,  it gives the first editText more room compared to the second one. if you want the two editText to have the same height then a space will be left on the upper part of the first editText. We can do that if you want to.

Comment: Why not use a LinearLayout? I updated the answer above and included the xml and image as well.

Comment: @ top margin - How would you do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9651/discussion-between-bogdan-marginean-and-mussharapp)

Comment: Do check the chat room when you get the time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving each of the `EditText` views a height of 0dp, and a `layout_weight` value of 1. Give it a shot and let me know if that works.

Comment: It might not; it's been a while since I've done any Android UI, so I'm rusty. :)

Comment: weight does not work with relative_layout :) thanks for the answer though!